# Как поместить слова из файла в разные переменные?

Tags: java

К примеру, мне нужно прочитать три слова из файла. Первое слово поместить в переменную `А`, второе - в `B`, и третье, соответственно, в `С`.

Файл имеет расширение TXT.

Хотелось бы что-то вроде такого:

```
 try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("C:\\input.txt"))
 {
     int c;
     while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
         System.out.print((char)c);
     } 
 }
 catch (IOException ex) {
     System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
 }
```

Но в данном примере я помещу всю информацию в одну переменную и читать её буду посимвольно, а надо по словам.

Comment: Если в файле слова разделены пробелом, то можно прочитать весь текст, а потом его разрезать на массив с помощью `string.split(" ")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Считываем файл построчно, бьём строки на слова по пробельным символам, после чего если слов вышло не меньше 3, то помещаем первые три слова в переменные `a`, `b` и `c`:

```
String a = null, b = null, c = null;
try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("test.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader))
{
    List<String> words = br.lines().flatMap(line -> Stream.of(line.split("\\s+")))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    if (words.size() >= 3)
    {
        a = words.get(0);
        b = words.get(1);
        c = words.get(2);
    }
}
catch (IOException ignored) { }
System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c);
```

Comment: А если будет несколько строк?

Comment: @AlexSMiheev а в чём проблема? В данном коде ведь считываются все строки из файла. Они хранятся в потоке `Stream<String>`, возвращаемом `br.lines()`, который потом и используется для получения слов из всех строк.

Comment: Отлично. Спасибо. + в карму и все такое=)

Comment: @AlexSMiheev на здоровье. Плюсовать ответы вы сможете только при достижении репутации 15, а вот принимать ответы (галочка слева от ответа), если они вас устраивают, вы можете в любой момент.